# Android Lineage OS - Not working on my 7inch Screen

Tags: pi-3

i'm new to using this group. Wondering if i could have some advice please?

I have installed Android Lineage OS to my Pi3, it works on my normal screens i have no problems. But my problem is when i plugin my 7 Inch touch screen via HDMI. I've added the the following code into the Config

```
max_usb_current=1 
hdmi_group=2 
hdmi_mode=1 
hdmi_mode=87 
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

which is suggested to the screen just goes black but the back light up still. When i take the code out of the config the screen goes green with lines running down. Would be great if i could get some help on what i should do please.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `hdmi_safe=1`?  Does it make a difference if you unplug the touch cable?

Comment: Would I add hdmi_safe=1 to the bottom of that other code?

Comment: I believe it overrides them all but you may want to comment out any other hdmi settings just to be sure.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this later.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not worked, it still a black screen (like it doesn't like that code at all) as when I take that code out it wants to load as I get the loading rainbow screen then goes off and goes to green with loads of black lines. I wonder if the OS is stopping it from working?

Comment: USB touchscreens are (potentially) standardised, meaning they don't need to require special drivers, but this is not necessarily so: Some do, ie., they extend or don't accord with some aspect of the applicable standards and so get distributed with special drivers.  That includes some things which are sold for the Pi (including I think the official touchscreen), and these require you install those unless they are already part of the normal kernel; how all this works out under Android on the Pi I don't know....

Comment: ...Finally, there are touchscreens which require special drivers but aren't sold for the Pi and don't support linux, with which you are out of luck.  That said, *I don't see why that would effect the HDMI*.  You might want to include some specifics in the question about the touchscreen itself (make and model, how it is attached).

Comment: http://www.lcdwiki.com/7inch_HDMI_Display-C

The link above is the screen I have ( 7inch HDMI LCD (C) USB capacitive Touch Screen 1024x600 Pixel)